# List upload destinations in module

Tags: add-on-development, module

I'd like to show a list of available upload destinations on a form in a custom module, are there functions to help with this?

Comment: Could you be a little more clear? There are add-ons like Assets that make this very trivial if you are concerned with content editors organizing their files. https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets. If you meant something else, please edit your question for clarity.

Comment: sorry, it's for a custom module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, just load and then use the File Upload Preferences model:

```
$group_id = ee()->session->userdata('group_id');
ee()->load->model('file_upload_preferences');
$upload_destinations = ee()->file_upload_preferences_model->get_file_upload_preferences($group_id);
```

Comment: Thank you, one correction: it's ee()->load->model('file_upload_preferences_model')